# How to use Mail Storage (offline)

Tags: storage

I'm interested in sending a copy of my hard drive (all data encrypted) to be physically stored away from my physical location, as a protection for archived data against loss from local physical dangers. I would be storing simply *one* external hard drive measuring less than a square foot in size. I'm trying to find a service who would accept and store such a small package as cheaply as possible, receiving it by mail and returning it by mail if requested. It doesn't have to be in any particular country. I'm based in the UK but could send abroad.

**Question**

How do I use mail storage, and what services provide the cheapest available services for storing very small quantities for long periods?

Comment: Quick questions for clarification. 1 Why are you wanting to send the hard disks away? 2 How often are you going to be updating or replacing the copy of the data.

Answer (score 1):

**MAIL STORAGE HACK**

You don't need to involve the postal service if you store your archive near you, accessible yet secure, in a local neighbourhood bank safety deposit box.

You can rent the boxes which are available in different sizes for a reasonable yearly rate. You can add, update, replace, or cancel at any time. Insurance is available. You might want to do an incremental back-up to a thumb drive which you can "toss it into the box" whenever you wish.

Why didn't I answer your specific question?

Every step involved increases the chances that something will happen to your data. Moving your hard drive to and from wherever it will be stored adds two extra, non-essential chances for loss or damage in transit.

Answer (score 0):

USB thumb drives are available for very little that will likely hold all your data, but are much smaller than your hard drive. That allows more storage options. I used a 500GB drive I bought for under $30 to store all my documents, including thousands of pictures. I put it in my bank safe-deposit box, but you might also  have a friend or relative who would like to do an exchange.